# Display column from SQL query with same name

Tags: php, html, mysql

how can I display the name of both teams (lteam and vteam)? Query works now... This is a screenshot of the SQL results:[image]
http://prntscr.com/f9mkqh

```
$sql = "
SELECT * 
  FROM fixtures 
  LEFT 
  JOIN teams AS a 
    ON fixtures.lteam = a.id
  LEFT 
  JOIN teams AS b 
    ON fixtures.vteam = b.id
 WHERE date_ko = '2017-05-19'
";
echo '<table>';
echo '<tbody>';

foreach($pdo->query($sql) as $row)
    {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['lteam'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>-</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['vteam'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['b.name'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }

echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The SQL result header is somewhat confusing, and as I don't know fully how the tables and schemas are structured, I have to assume you are having trouble with getting the `name` attribute from the `teams` table, as this is joined in two times.

You will need to select the columns explicitly and naming them something else for this to work. For example:

```
SELECT *, `a`.`name` as `team1name`, `b`.`name` as `team2name` FROM fixtures [...]
```

Now you should be able to grab the team names under their assigned aliases.

Comment: You are the boss! Thanks!